# Vaccination policies

Tags: data-request, medical, global

I am looking for a data set containing vaccination policies by country, and if possible by year. Ideally, the vaccination policy would be stored in some machine-readable format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WHO has some Excel tables that indicate vaccination policy for individual countries and individual vaccinations.

http://www.who.int/immunization/monitoring_surveillance/data/en/

> 6. Immunization schedule. Data are available for:
>
> 6.1 Reported immunization schedules by vaccine in html and in excel
>
> 6.2 Year of introduction of selected vaccines database in excel
>
> 6.3 Immunization schedules by disease covered by antigens within age range 
>   in html
>
> 6.4 Immunization provided at school in excel
>
> 6.5 Slides on introduction status of selected vaccines

The the 2nd sheet in the [Excel file](http://www.who.int/entity/immunization/monitoring_surveillance/data/schedule_data.xls) for point 6.1 above has the data you are looking for.

[image]