# Vaccination success rates

Tags: data-request, medical, global

I am looking for a data set containing vaccination success rates with as many following fields as possible:

- percentage of patients who received the vaccination but are not immune to the medical condition they have been vaccinated against;
- percentage of patients with strongly negative reaction to the vaccination;
- year
- patient demographics

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [your other question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/9345/1511), the WHO data sets may cover this question

http://www.who.int/immunization/monitoring_surveillance/data/en/

In particular

> 3. Disease incidence: data usually represent only a fraction of the cases, but are useful to monitor trends.
>
> 3.1 Reported incidence time series is available in html and in excel
>
> 3.2 Polio case count data
>
> 3.3 Monthly measles surveillance data
>
> 4. Immunization coverage
>
> 4.1 Official country reported coverage estimates time series are available in html and in excel
>
> 4.2 Download Country reported administrative data time series in excel
>
> 4.3 WHO/UNICEF Estimates of National Immunization Coverage (WUENIC) are available in html and in excel. Also see the the country summaries
>   (in pdf), content of PDF in excel and the method.
>
> 4.4 Coverage Survey Data in excel